# javascript + div tags

Tags: javascript, nodes, names

these days i read and learn more about my problem!the code is here:

```
<div align="right" id="parent" name="parent">
<select name="select30" id="select30" value=""/>here inside i have options values and work dynamically with query to my DB</select>
<input type="button" id="moreFields" value="+" onclick=""/> //add select tags
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="" /> //remove select tags
<div name="child" id="writeclone"></div> //here cloned the  child from parent DIV 
</div>
<input type="button" name="enter" id="" value="ENTER" onclick="getoptionvalues();"/>
```

My problem is how i can get the names or id's from child DIV when + button fired.When this button fired create child DIVs in Child DIV!!Can anybody HELP ME to correct my JAVASCRIPT code

```
<script>
function getoptionvalues() {
    var parent=document.getElementById('parent');
    for (var count=0;count<parent.childNodes.length;count++) {
        if(parent.childNodes[count].tagName =='DIV') {
            alert ('parent.childNodes[count]');
        }
    } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: `alert ('parent.childNodes[count]');` should be `alert (parent.childNodes[count]);`

Answer (score 2):

As ThiefMaster pointed out, `'parent.childNodes[count]'` should be `parent.childNodes[count]`. Then to get the id, it is just `.id` and name is `.name`

```
    if(parent.childNodes[count].tagName =='DIV') {
        alert (parent.childNodes[count].id);
        alert (parent.childNodes[count].name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you need to add a method name to your onClick:

```
<input type="button" id="moreFields" value="+" onclick="$:getoptionvalues()"/>
```

Then, using jquery, you can grab an array of components of a certain type, and then loop through w/ alerts:

```
function getoptionvalues() {
    var dropdownMenus = $("select");
    dropdownMens.each(function () {
        var id = $(this).id;
        alert(id);
    });
}
```

Comment: As ubiquitous a jQuery is, it wasnt part of the question. Also `onclick="getoptionvalues()"` should work just fine. Why do you say that he needs the `$:`??

Comment: You're probably right.  I've been writing too much MVC lately, and I think the $: is necessary in that case.

Comment: hello again and thanks a lot for answers but nothing happend when i press the button!can you see please your jquery code?if you want more details for my code please tell me !i read all the time and looking on forums but no solution!